# Google Rio 2016 Like Animation

Tags: jquery, animation

I'm currently building a new website, in which I would like to corporate something that Google is doing as well with some of their widgets (I'm sure other websites do as well.)

I would like to have the website to have an animation to another tab, a little like the Google GIF I included. I know how to do the animation, but it has to get to another tab without having to go to another tab while it shouldn't be clear it's reloading, which I don't know how to do.

Do any of you have any idea which framework or something I have to use? Should I use jQuery, or what else? I can look things up myself, but I would like to know how to get started with it, since I have no idea...

[Link to GIF with example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U0Em9.gif)

Thanks in advance,

R. Baauw

Comment: If you're looking to load dynamic content on your page (to avoid leaving the current page), you'll need to use Ajax. There are plenty of tutorials out there, you just need to adapt it so that it appears in your animated container. If the content is already available on your page (but not visible), then it's easy, just show it with the animation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a `Single Page Web Application`, you can make `SPA` using any modern frontend framework. `AngularJS` is one such framework.

You can use frontend router to achieve this functionality as well.

`AngularJS` has `ngRoute` for this purpose.

You can use [`Aviator`](https://github.com/swipely/aviator) which again a SPA router.